# Flutter not on android studio list

Tags: android-studio, flutter

After installing flutter and dart and developing mini apk ,I[image] couldn't find "create new flutter apk" option in my android studio list after closing android studio and then reopening it
please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check whether the Flutter and Dart plugins are installed or not. Probably it's because the plugins that are not installed or removed somehow.

Comment: that's true but there still one more thing , check disabled plugins text files and delete them from C\:User\Library\AndroidStudio4.0\config

Comment: or maybe just remove the particular plugin from the file you want to enable again but the question is how they ended up in the disabled plugins text file in the first place?
Maybe you clicked on the disable option by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Go In Android Studio In Tools --> SDK Manager --> Plugins

[image]

And Install Flutter Plugin and then you can Use **Flutter** In Android Studio